# Blank Fatal Error Not Specified on Apache Server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

PHP is returning an unspecified error:

> Fatal error: in C:\Users\user\Desktop\USBWebserver v8.6\root\uploads de documentos pdf - PHP - MySQL\index.php on line 87

And on this line 87, is the following line of code:

```
$db = new PDO('odbc:SAMPLE', 'db2inst1', 'ibmdb2');
```

And this line of code was taken from the condition that it will display the document stored in a browser database if the `$_GET['abrirdoc']` request exists:

```
if (isset($_GET['abrirdoc'])) {
    $db = new PDO('odbc:SAMPLE', 'db2inst1', 'ibmdb2');
    $stmt = $db->prepare("select tipo, conteudo from docs where id=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($_GET['abrirdoc']));
    $stmt->bindColumn(1, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
    $stmt->bindColumn(2, $lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

    header("Content-Type: $type");
    fpassthru($lob);
}
```

What is happening? What would be the possible solution to solve this problem?

Note: Please note that all PDO extensions are enabled in the `php.ini` server configuration file.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the full error message?

Comment: yes, I found it very strange

Comment: because in this application I use the MySQL database along with PHP

Comment: try `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()); ` and make sure odbc is in the list, if it is your issue is probably on the odbc setting side and not php

Comment: that may be but why did you use $db = new PDO('odbc:SAMPLE'  but in the php manual it should be $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

Comment: I put the first command you entered and returned the driver array, but inserting the line you put in the next comment still causes the same code error. I see no sense in this, but if you could put a tentative solution here in this post, I would be grateful.